# How much has Disney revealed about Moff Gideon?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

**Spoilers for The Mandalorian ahead.**

So, in The Mandalorian, Moff Gideon is the main antagonist, really. I'm wondering how much we know.

I already know:

- He was an ex-ISB officer
- He wielded the Darksaber after taking it from Bo-Katan Kryze
- All other details revealed in The Mandalorian, such as he wants to use Grogu's blood

Has Disney made any other official announcements? I don't keep up with the news, only the shows/movies and sometimes the books.

Comment: Some info https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gideon